# Braintree - Android SDK: existing card verification by just passing CVV for processing payment

Tags: android, braintree

I have integrated Braintree Android SDK in studio for payment process. Instead of using Drop-in UI I am using my customised UI which has 3 tabs - Saved Cards, New Card and Cash. In Saved card - the list of saved cards is displayed while in New card - user is prompt to enter Card no, expiration date and CVV and the option to save the card details and for payment through cash - cash tab is used, card details are not saved in front / back end everything is working fine. But my requirement is - if user selects existing card for payment then my application wants to prompt user to enter CVV of the existing card for authorization.

I am using CardBuilder.java to build card details for newly entered card which is,

```
CardBuilder cardBuilder = new CardBuilder()
    .cardNumber(mEdtCardNumber.getText().toString())
    .expirationDate(mEdtExpirationYear.getText().toString())
    .cvv(mEdtCvv.getText().toString());

Card.tokenize(mBraintreeFragment, cardBuilder);
```

and am getting nounce in `onPaymentMethodNonceCreated`.

And for existing card after entering CVV am using same process like,

```
CardBuilder cardBuilder = new CardBuilder().cvv(entered CVV);
Card.tokenize(mBraintreeFragment, cardBuilder);
```

but my `onPaymentMethodNonceCreated` is not getting called and instead onError is called and the error is,

```
{"error":{"message":“Credit card is invalid”},
“fieldErrors”:[{"field":“creditCard”,
“fieldErrors”:[{"field":“expirationDate”,“code”:“81709”,“message”:“Expiration date is required”},
{"field":“number”,“code”:“81714”,“message”:“Credit card number is required”},
{"field":“base”,“code”:“81725”,“message”:“Credit card must include number, payment_method_nonce, or venmo_sdk_payment_method_code”}]}]}
```

But the same thing is working in iOS client SDK.

So my concern is, it is the right way to validate existing card or there is another way. Braintree - Drop In UI doesn't ask for CVV on existing card payment and I am also not getting any code in their API. I have gone through whole API and counld't find any such thing.

Where as, the backend PHP is used to make payment method calls, from front end I am just passing the nounce.

Can anyone please help me how to validate existing card by CVV?

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I need to allow users to edit existing card info. I do not have the CC number to pass to tokenize. This works on iOS but not on Android.

Comment: look at answer below....

Comment: @NikhilSohoni Can you tell me the PCI compliance level of company for which you are developing this? Is is SAQ A or higher?

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with the folks at BrainTree, here is what you need to do:
When setting up the CardBuilder make sure you set the following flag
CardBuilder cardBuilder = new CardBuilder()
                .validate(false),.....
This will return a nonce without validating the card number which you do not have.